# Get FileModification/Creation time of a file on a webserver

Tags: java, android

Howdy,
I'm currentyl new to Java and Android but I would like to write an App which checks a webserver on a particular file. If that file is NEWER than the locally saved file it should go ahead and download the file.

Now I've already got the download in place .. but I don't know how I can check the file on the webserver. Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into sending your request with an `If-Modified-Since` header. This makes your request conditional based on the resource you are requesting. If it hasn't been updated since that time, it will return a 304.

See Section 14.25 of [this page](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) for more details.

Comment: Howdy,thanks for yor help. You pointed me into the right direction. The way I solved it was: 

URLConnection con = url.openConnection();  
Date lastModified = new Date(con.getLastModified());

Comment: You're welcome, and if that is the case you should accept an answer to mark it as a solved issue. =)